# Customizing Datepicker JavaFX 8

Tags: css, datepicker, javafx-8

How can I customize CSS in Datepicker JavaFX 8 ?
I need to remove the light blue shadow or define how to light grey.

Thanks.

Comment: Use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) and/or look at the default modena.css. It looks like DatePicker gets all its css rules from combo-box-base. I'm not sure what "light blue shadow" you are referring to, unless it's the focus highlight.

Answer (score 1):

the datePicker is a ComboBoxBase. The light blue shadow is the background when focused, so:

```
.combo-box-base:focused {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

will make the job.

bye
T